# Process Cpu time increases gradually

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

In our linux systems we observe that cpu load, heap usage of a java server is normal but OperatingSystem.ProcessCpuTime is gradually increasing, drops to minimum value and increased again. 
We have 2 cores in linux system.

[image: process cpu time]

could you clarify me on these below:

1) as example in above picture, what is the meaning of "10,000,000,000,000" process cpu time? I searched in internet is that returned value is in nanoseconds.

2) What could be the reason for gradual increment even though it is dropping to minimum value? Is this normal behavior? Sometimes it reaches to 90,000,000,000,000 and we will restart the java process as it will not respond correctly.

3) How can I troubleshoot this situation.

I searched in internet but couldn't found correct answer which i was expecting.